# Android webview fails to load javascript and css files

Tags: java, android, angular

I have an Angular web app and i want to run it locally inside a WebView of my android app. When opening the app i get a blank screen.

When opening the chrome inspect tool i get a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error on the .js and .css files, so the index.html file is found, but the other files which are refered to in the index.html file aren't loaded.

It looks like it is looking in the wrong directory for the files, which is strange, because all of the files are present in the assets folder.

The code:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }

        wv = findViewById(R.id.webView);;
        wv.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        wv.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

I've tried several things from other SO topics, but i just can't get it working.

The html file:

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Homecontrol</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.6b8a2f2753f016f4d661.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
<script src="runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.ef4b1e1fc703b3ff76e3.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.9c4c062fd851d4ee0231.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.9c4c062fd851d4ee0231.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by adding the following code to the WebView config.

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public String getMimeType(String url) {
                String type = null;
                String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
                if (extension != null) {
                    if (extension.equals("js")) {
                        return "text/javascript";
                    }
                    else if(extension.equals("html")) {
                        return "text/html";
                    }
                    else if (extension.equals("woff")) {
                        return "application/font-woff";
                    }
                    else if (extension.equals("woff2")) {
                        return "application/font-woff2";
                    }
                    else if (extension.equals("ttf")) {
                        return "application/x-font-ttf";
                    }
                    else if (extension.equals("eot")) {
                        return "application/vnd.ms-fontobject";
                    }
                    else if (extension.equals("svg")) {
                        return "image/svg+xml";
                    }
                    type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                }
                return type;
            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.contains(baseUrl)) {
                    url = url.replace(baseUrl, "");

                    try {
                        return new WebResourceResponse(getMimeType(url), "UTF-8", getAssets().open(url));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });


        wv.loadUrl(baseUrl + "index.html");
```